# Matplotlib turn off antialias for text in plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, antialiasing

Is there any way to turn off antialias for all text in a plot, especially the ticklabels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is not possible. Some classes such as Line2D have a "set_antialiased" method, but Text lacks this. I suggest you file a feature request on the Sourceforge tracker, and send an email to the matplotlib mailing list mentioning the request.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it already existed back in 2010, but I had the same issue and found that matplotlib has a text.antialiased parameter that applies to the tick labels too. Tested with the agg and cairo backends:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['text.antialiased'] = False
plt.plot([0,1,2], [3,4,5])
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the anti-aliasing of Text objects is up to the font engine being used.  [It seems the freetype2 fonts support this.](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/text_intro.html)